# Event listener on a CSS pseudo-element, such as ::after and ::before?

Tags: javascript, css, pseudo-element

I have a `div` element with a CSS pseudo-element `::before` used as a close button (instead of using an actual button). How do I apply an event listener to *only* the pseudo-element?

**HTML**

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#box:before
{
 background-image: url(close.png);
 content: '';
 display: block; 
 height: 20px;
 position: absolute;
 top: -10px;
 right: -10px; 
 width: 20px;
}

#box
{
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Maybe check this question for some ideas http://stackoverflow.com/q/5598675/10696

Comment: Not what you asked for, but in practice you could instead just add a span element and add event listeners to your heart's desire.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

No. The pseudo-element does not exist in the DOM so it has no `HTMLElementNode` object representing it.

Comment: What's a "HTMLElementNode object"?

Comment: An instance of the [class](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-1-20000929/level-one-html.html#ID-58190037) that has the event binding methods on it.

Comment: @derek this answer is still true - you cannot assign an event to a pseudo element. Declaring pointer-events is a nice workaround but only in case where you don't need other event listeners on div#box itself or other child elements in div#box.

Comment: @MosheYakov, point about workaround taken onboard; have removed my downvote. Thanks.

Answer (score 80):

Was looking for a solution and found this thread. Now want to share my workaround:

**CSS**

```
element { pointer-events: none; }
element::after { pointer-events: all; }
```

**JS**

```
element.addEventListener('click', function() { ... });
```

This works if you don't need any pointer events on `element`. Check it in [action](https://jsfiddle.net/fqhk7dea/).

Comment: This should be the accepted solution. There are two problems with pointer-events, though: 1) you block the container element from holding other event listeners (which you probably don't want anyway); and 2) more importantly, pointer-events cascade, so you have to allow it back on everything else that needs interaction.

Comment: Would adding something like `element * { pointer-events: default }` work as to fixing number 2?

Comment: @AdamRaichu not sure what particularly you are asking about: selector or CSS property. BTW, MDN doesn't list `default` among values and `all` should work on SVG, though it works on HTML as well. That said, `auto` should be used instead of `all` on HTML elements

Answer (score 15):

There is no :before and :after selector in jQuery. However as an alternative, you can check the location of the click event and check if it is on your pseudo-element:

*(I haven't tested this)*

style:

```
#mything {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    background: blue;
}
#mything:after {
    content: "x";
    font-size: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: red;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}
```

javascript:

```
$('#mything').click(function(e) {
    if (e.clientX > $(this).offset().left + 90 &&
        e.clientY < $(this).offset().top + 10) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

html:

```
<div id="mything">Foo</div>
```

Comment: Up, solved my problem but with `getBoundingClientRect()` instead of jQuerys `offset()`

Answer (score 2):

If the position and dimensions of the generated content are known, you can add a click handler on the element itself and check the [relative mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234256/find-mouse-position-relative-to-element) before handling it.

This is perverse, but possible.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking no as indicated by others.  **But in case your tag with pseudo-element is empty**, such as [glyphicon in bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/).

You can wrap a `div` or `span` or whatever tag suitable in your case. [Glyphicons in bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) uses `:before` but on the page you can see that it has `hover` event caught.

Example:

```
<span>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</span>
```

Suppose you want to add event to the above glyphicon, you can use [jquery parent selector](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

```
$('glyphicon').parent('span').click(function() { 
  // awesome things
});
```

Just a small trick **in case your tag is empty**.

Comment: This isn't capturing the event on the pseudo-element but rather the parent element and, therefore, is not a valid answer.

Answer (score -1):

I wanted to add my answer to this old post. This method is dynamic and works inside of the DOM-element, by calculating the width of the pseudo element, and checking if the user clicked there.

It works with vanilla JavaScript in all modern browsers and IE >= 9.

```js
// Select the input element and its pseudo-element :after
const input = document.querySelector('.input');
const computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(input, ':after');
const pseudoWidth = parseInt(computedStyle.width ?? 0) + parseInt(computedStyle.paddingLeft ?? 0) + parseInt(computedStyle.paddingRight ?? 0);

// Add a click event listener to the input element
input.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  // Check if the click occurred on the pseudo-element :after
  if (e.offsetX >= input.offsetWidth - pseudoWidth) {
    console.log("Clicked on pseudo-element :after");
  }
});
```

```css
.input {
  position: relative;
  width: min-content;
}

.input::after {
  content: 'x';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0 5px;
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="input">
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```