# How to add css property to jquery variable pseudo selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can anyone help me to set top position for $myClass before and after. Below is my code that I tried.

```
var $myClass = $(".myclass");
$myClass.filter(":before,:after").css("top",-23);
```

Comment: You cannot select pseudo elements like `:before` through jQuery.

Comment: you can add another class to your css with :before and after then use $myClass.addClass('newclass'); or  $myClass.removeClass('newclass'); or $myClass.toggleClass('newclass')

Answer (score 0):

Try appending a `style` element to document , including properties , values for `.myclass:before` , `.myclass:after` at `style` `text`

```
$("<style>", {"text":".myclass:before,.myclass:after{top:-23}"})
.appendTo("body");
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/27255808/

Comment: Whats is the difference between this one and yours.

\\  $(".myclass:after,.myclass:after").css("top",-23);  \\

Comment: @prakashstar42 `$(".myclass:after,.myclass:after")` does not select the `pseudo` elements . Appending a `style` element to document sets properties for `.myclass:before` , `.myclass:after`  `css` selectors

Comment: @prakashstar42 See http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-pseudo-4/ _"Pseudo-elements represent abstract elements of the document beyond those elements explicitly created by the document language."_ ; see also http://nicolasgallagher.com/an-introduction-to-css-pseudo-element-hacks/ _"As their names imply, they are not part of the DOM in the way that ‘real’ HTML elements and classes are. Instead, they are CSS abstractions that provide additional, and otherwise inaccessible, information about the document."_

Comment: @prakashstar42 Tried `js` at post ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have used addClass property to solve this. Thanks again