# jQuery remove all before pseudo elements except first and last

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to remove all pseudo before elements except first and last in an unsorted list using jQuery or JavaScript?

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li id="menu-item-241">
        ::before
        <a href="">
            <span>Some text</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-242">
        ::before
        <a href="">
            <span>Some text</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-243">
        ::before
        <a href="">
            <span>Some text</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-244">
        ::before
        <a href="">
            <span>Some text</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-245">
        ::before
        <a href="">
            <span>Some text</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-246">
        ::before
        <a href="">
            <span>Some text</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Obviously I'm not going to hide each before element with css for each menu item id so what's the most efficient way? Thanks for your time.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/27255808/

Comment: You can use `:first-child` and `:last-child` selectors in your `CSS` to capture only first and last `li`.

Comment: @aje OP is trying to select `css` pseudo elements.