# Modify element :before CSS rules programmatically in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have an element whose `:before` style has to be modified based on calculations.

```
export class Content extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="ring-base">
               <div className="ring-left" style={{/* Change here */}}></div>
               <div className="ring-right" style={{/* Change here */}}></div>
               <div className="ring-cover">
                   <div className="ring-text">10%</div>
               </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

CSS Code:

```
.ring-base {
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: red;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    overflow:hidden;
}
.ring-cover {
    position: absolute;
    height: 180px;
    width: 180px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 5%;
    left: 5%;
}

.ring-cover .ring-text {
    position: absolute;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-content:center;
    flex-direction:column;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.ring-right, .ring-left {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;  
}

.ring-right:before, .ring-left:before {
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0;
    background-color: grey;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.ring-right {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    transform: rotateZ(0deg);
}

.ring-left {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
}

.ring-right:before {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.ring-left:before {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);

}
```

The ask is to be able to update the transform property for `.ring-left:before` and `.ring-right:before` via ReactJS.

If there is a way to not update the `:before` class and change the CSS to not make use of `:before` at all, then do suggest that as well.

[Js-Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dsupreme/6y6mfjw0/2/)

Comment: Create new tag `<style>` and put your calculations as content, append to `head` or `body`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/27255808/

Comment: @Justinas are you refering to dangerously setting html ? Is this what i should try ? (https://medium.learnreact.com/the-style-tag-and-react-24d6dd3ca974#.mgeig2yf2)

Comment: @guest271314 I do not know how to use Jquery in React. Is there any non JQuery way ?

Comment: @ManmeetS.Oberoi: Attention please, do not use jQuery with ReactJS

Comment: @ManmeetS.Oberoi Why do you think setting HTML dynamically is dangerous?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can iterate `document.styleSheets`, set `.style` of `.cssRules` where `.selectorText` matches pseudo selector

```js
let sheets = document.styleSheets;
let selector = "div::before";
let replacementContent = '"after"';
for (let sheet of sheets) {
  for (let rule of sheet.cssRules) {
    if (rule.selectorText === selector) {
      rule.style["content"] = replacementContent;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
div:before {
  content: "before";
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
  background: green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Wow, this is quite nice. Saving as bookmark, this might come handy in the future.

Comment: This does the trick and works as expected. Thanks. Do suggest a react way to replicate the same if possible.

Comment: @ManmeetS.Oberoi Not sure what  "react way" is. Approach at Answer set properties at `CSSStyleSheet` loaded at `document`.

Comment: This is a brute force way of iterating over all the stylesheets added to the project and then searching for the selector. If we could add a dynamically generate a class with pseudo element support and then add it to the specific component.

Comment: @ManmeetS.Oberoi You could toggle `.className` of element to apply `css` pseudo element rule to the class. Or, add,  remove element having `.className`  where pseudo element is set at `css`. The present Question asks how to modify an existing `css` `::before` pseudo element rule.