# Add transition atfer uploading background image to localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, transition

I would like to know how can I add transition (fade effect) after uploading an image to localstorage?

```js
$(switchBackground);
var oFReader = new FileReader(),
  rFilter = /^(?:image\/bmp|image\/cis\-cod|image\/gif|image\/ief|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/pipeg|image\/png|image\/svg\+xml|image\/tiff|image\/x\-cmu\-raster|image\/x\-cmx|image\/x\-icon|image\/x\-portable\-anymap|image\/x\-portable\-bitmap|image\/x\-portable\-graymap|image\/x\-portable\-pixmap|image\/x\-rgb|image\/x\-xbitmap|image\/x\-xpixmap|image\/x\-xwindowdump)$/i;

oFReader.onload = function(oFREvent) {
  localStorage.setItem('b', oFREvent.target.result);
  switchBackground();
};

function switchBackground() {
  var backgroundImage = localStorage.getItem('b');
  if (backgroundImage) {
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + backgroundImage + ')');
  }
}

function loadImageFile(testEl) {
  if (!testEl.files.length) {
    return;
  }
  var oFile = testEl.files[0];
  if (!rFilter.test(oFile.type)) {
    alert("You must select a valid image file!");
    return;
  }
  oFReader.readAsDataURL(oFile);
}
```

```html
<input id="test" type="file" onchange="loadImageFile(this)" />
```

Comment: How are you storing image in local storage? You mean to say url?  And local storage is synchronous, so image storing in local storage has nothing to do with fade effect.

Answer (score 0):

CSS `background-image` property of a DOM element does not have a built-in means to animate.

CSS pseudo element can be animated. You can use `:after` CSS pseudo element with `width` set to the `calc(100vw)` and `height` set to `calc(100vh)` to cover the viewport, and `animation` property set where corresponding `keyframes` animate the pseudo element `content` property value  from `opacity` `0` to `opacity` `1`. If `backgroundImage` is not `null`, append CSS text to `<style>` element which sets `content` property of `body` `:after` pseudo element with `content` set to CSS `url()` function to the `data URL` retrieved from `localStorage`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    body:after {
      position: relative; /* set `position` to `relative`
      content: unset; /* set `content` to `unset`  */
      width: calc(100vw); /*  width of viewport */
      height: calc(100vh); /* height of viewport */ 
      animation: bg 5s ease forwards; /* `iteration-timing-function` set to `forwards` */
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(switchBackground);

    var oFReader = new FileReader(),
      rFilter = /^(?:image\/bmp|image\/cis\-cod|image\/gif|image\/ief|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/pipeg|image\/png|image\/svg\+xml|image\/tiff|image\/x\-cmu\-raster|image\/x\-cmx|image\/x\-icon|image\/x\-portable\-anymap|image\/x\-portable\-bitmap|image\/x\-portable\-graymap|image\/x\-portable\-pixmap|image\/x\-rgb|image\/x\-xbitmap|image\/x\-xpixmap|image\/x\-xwindowdump)$/i;

    oFReader.onload = function(oFREvent) {
      localStorage.setItem('b', oFREvent.target.result);
      switchBackground();
    };

    function switchBackground() {
      var backgroundImage = localStorage.getItem('b');
      if (backgroundImage) {
        // set `body:after` `content` to `data URL`: `backgroundImage`
        $("style").append(`body:after{content:url(${backgroundImage})} @keyframes bg {from {opacity:0}to {opacity:1)}}`);
      }
    }

    function loadImageFile(testEl) {
      if (!testEl.files.length) {
        return;
      }
      var oFile = testEl.files[0];
      if (!rFilter.test(oFile.type)) {
        alert("You must select a valid image file!");
        return;
      }
      oFReader.readAsDataURL(oFile);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input id="test" type="file" onchange="loadImageFile(this)" />
</body>
</html>
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/b29hbGi6meodd2LTEgFL?p=preview

Comment: It's not working. Background has no transition and the remove button removes the image only after refreshing the page.

   `function removeImageFile()
    {
    localStorage.removeItem('b');
    switchBackground();
    }`

Comment: Background has transition but the remove button I added is working only after refresh.

Comment: @Mix911  _"but the remove button I added is working only after refresh"_ Neither the question nor the code mentions a "remove button". See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-askThe CSS appended to the `<style>` element `.textContent` needs to be adjusted or removed if the expected result is to remove the `content` of the pseudo element, see [Modify element :before CSS rules programmatically in React](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42619084/)

Comment: I know. I added a code to my comment. And it's not working.