# Assign CSS to a background via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my first time trying to change my html background by pressing a button. I've a CSS which I teste in the body tage by doing  and that worked. However, when I used a JavaSript function to change the background only when the button is pushed, the code doesn't run.

This is my CSS:

```
.chiefs{
background: #E31837;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #E31837 0%, #FFFFFF 50%, #FFB612 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #E31837 0%, #FFFFFF 50%, #FFB612 100%);
background: linear-gradient(135deg, #E31837 0%, #FFFFFF 50%, #FFB612 100%);
}
```

This is my HTML with an internal JavaScript:

```
<main>
<button onClick="myFunc()" id="game">Chiefs</button>
</main>

<script> 
function myFunc(){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "chiefs";
}

</script>
```

I'm unsure what to put in the script section after I define myFunc.

I tried multiple different definitions and functions but they only worked for a solid color. For example, with a button I could change the background color to green by just typing 'green' but since I have a gradient CSS, I don't know what to do.

Comment: What are you expecting "chiefs" to do? Technically you can iterate the style sheet rules, get the value defined for `.chiefs` and assign that value to `document.body.style.backgroundColor`, see [Modify element :before CSS rules programmatically in React](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42619630/).

Comment: You are passing class as color. That won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.classList.add()` instead, since `chiefs` is a CSS class, not a color.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

```css
.chiefs{
background: #E31837;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #E31837 0%, #FFFFFF 50%, #FFB612 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #E31837 0%, #FFFFFF 50%, #FFB612 100%);
background: linear-gradient(135deg, #E31837 0%, #FFFFFF 50%, #FFB612 100%);
}
This is my HTML with an internal JavaScript:
```

```html
<main>
<button onClick="myFunc()" id="game">Chiefs</button>
</main>

<script> 
function myFunc(){
    document.body.classList.add("chiefs");
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared **".chiefs"** as a CSS class, you can not assign it a css property. It is not a property. You should apply it to the body element instead of setting the background color property. That's why when you set solid color works, otherwise not works. Try following:

```
<script> 
function myFunc() {
    document.body.classList.add("chiefs");
}
</script>
```