# how can we change property of sudo classes as like :before and :after in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was creating custom accordion it created but the problem is i need to a plus and minus icon on that accordion when i click on accordion the plus sign the accordion opens and plus sign changes in minus sign and vice versa  below is code given Thanks in Advance); The plus sign changes on active accordion not for all. i mean i will click on first accordion the plus sign of first accordion changes rest will remain same

HTML

```
<h2>Accordion</h2>

<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

js

```
<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName('accordion');
var i;
for(i=0;i < acc.length;i++){
acc[i].onclick = function(){
var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
if(panel.style.display =="block"){
panel.style.display ="none";
}
else{
panel.style.display ="block";
panel.class
}
}
}
</script>
```

Csss

```
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd; 
}
button.accordion:before{
  content: '\002B';
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
div.panel {
    padding: 4px 20px;
    display: none;
    background-color: #ddd;
     margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/gncrhc5a/

Comment: @ Rehban Khatri but i need it in javascript not in jquery.... if don't mind can you plzz udate the fiddle with your code that will apppericiated

Comment: See also [JQuery select pseudo-element :after](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27254674/jquery-select-pseudo-element-after/)

Comment: @ guest271314 can you please update my fiddle so that i can get it easily

Comment: Have you tried to implement either of the two linked approaches?

Comment: @ guest271314 47 yes i did that already

Comment: @ guest271314 47 i did it with jquery but problem is now that when i click first accordion the plus sign should be change for first but it changes all three accordions i think there should be use of either index or active class but i don't know how to use that can you please help me in that scenario i am giving u my Fiddle   https://jsfiddle.net/gncrhc5a/2/

Answer (score 0):

After re-reading the Question, the "duplicate" vote was not appropriate. `javascript` at Question does not actually attempt to change `css` `:before` or `:after`, but rather, toggle `.className` of element.

At `javascript` you were missing `c` after `fun` at `$("button").click(funtion(){`; change `$(".accordion").removeClass('accordion-icon').addClass('minus-icon')` to `$(this).toggleClass('accordion-icon minus-icon')` to reference current `button` element, instead of all `.accordion` elements.

At `css` if you want the `"-"` to be rendered at same position of `"+"`, the same `css` should be applied at `.minus-icon:before` selector, except for `content` property.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".accordion").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("accordion-icon minus-icon").next(".panel").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
button.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.accordion-icon:before {
  content: '\002B';
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.minus-icon:before {
  content: "\2212";
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

div.panel {
  padding: 4px 20px;
  display: none;
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Accordion</h2>

<button class="accordion accordion-icon">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion accordion-icon">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion accordion-icon">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```