# Change line-clamp style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a testimonials page for my site, and some of the testimonials I have are rather long. As such I want to cut out anything longer than 3 lines.

To read the rest, the user clicks a button and the text expands to reveal the rest.

I've managed to do the above with `line-clamp`, however I'd like to have the `...` clickable and styled with a different text. Is this possible?

I couldn't find a way to do that, so I tried a workaround. First I find out which elements have overflow so the `[Read More]` can be inserted. However it gets inserted at the end of the text, and not before the overflow.

I'm clueless as to how to solve this.

#### Desired result:

[image]

[**Current result (jsfiddle)**](http://jsfiddle.net/6nb0wwc3/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="testimonial container-fluid">
    <div class="col-xs-3 rating-container">
        <div>
            <div class="star"></div>
            <div class="star"></div>
            <div class="star"></div>
            <div class="star"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <div class="title">Title</div>
        <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vero essent gubergren ad pro, regione epicuri contentiones ea mea. Decore omnium id vim, pro et malis molestie, et porro nostro vis. Ei libris debitis reprehendunt est. Te per delenit scaevola scripserit. Partem erroribus rationibus ea vel, nihil euismod ei vim.

            His sonet antiopam cotidieque ea, eu unum melius conclusionemque his. Ferri iisque sanctus pri ei. Ut ius tantas nonumy intellegam. Et per solum aliquam, melius elaboraret at qui.</div>
        <div class="name_loc" id="demo">Name, London</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.testimonial {
    width: 920px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    color: #333;
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    border: 3px solid #506790;
}

.testimonial:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
}

.testimonial .rating-container {
    height: 144px;
    display: table;
}

.testimonial .rating-container > div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.testimonial .star {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url('http://www.timelinecoverbanner.com/cliparts/wp-content/digital-scrapbooking/lemon-star-md1.png');
    background-size: cover;
}

.testimonial .title {
    font-size: 18pt;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.testimonial .content {
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    display: -webkit-box;
    margin: 5px 0 10px;
    font-size: 12pt;
    text-align: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 68px;
}

.testimonial .name_loc {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 12pt;
    text-align: right;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('#demo').on('click', function() {
    var t = $(this).closest('.testimonial');
    var c = t.find('.content');         
    var h3 = c[0].scrollHeight;             
    c.animate({'height':h3},500);
});

$('.testimonial').each(function() {
    var c = $(this).find('.content');       
    if (c.height() < c[0].scrollHeight) {
        c.css('text-overflow', 'ellipsis');
        //also tried:
        c.css('line-clamp', '3');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with the ::after pseudo-element. I was playing with your fiddle and it seemed to work.

First the .content class needs to be positioned relative. Then add two new CSS classes:

```
.testimonial .content.collapsed {
/* styles removed from .content */
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 68px;
}
.testimonial .content.collapsed::after {
    display: inline-block;
    content: "...";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 5px;
}
```

You could add the click handler to the pseudo  element in the JS (I didn't try this part), and then remove the "collapsed" class after the click. You could also style the pseudo element any way you want, or change the content to "Read more..." or whatever.

Comment: Looks promising, but could you please provide a jsfiddle? I tried doing what you said but I must have done something wrong because it didn't work.

Comment: I started from what you had: http://jsfiddle.net/7ko160sc/ It would need to be cleaned up a bit, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: you can't bind click event to pseudo elements: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395858/event-listener-on-a-css-pseudo-element-such-as-before-or-after

Comment: Good point (guess that's why I had some trouble). In my fiddle I bound it to the .content

Answer (score 0):

Try fiddling with your [**revised JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/agspmzhq/). It uses:

```
$('.testimonial').on( 
    'click', 
    '.content',
    function(e) {
      if (this.scrollHeight > this.offsetHeight) {
          $(this).removeClass('clipped')
                 .addClass('unclipped')
                 .css('height', this.scrollHeight+'px');
      } else {
          $(this).removeClass('unclipped')
                 .addClass('clipped')
                 .css('height', '');
      }
    }
);
```

and 2 extra css-classes: `clipped` and `unclipped`:

```
.clipped:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '>';
    top: 2.9em;
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.unclipped:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '<';
    top: 2.9em;
    color: green;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: The arrow seems off in your fiddle. but it's a nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

What about this: http://jsfiddle.net/6nb0wwc3/1/

I added a "readme" div, which on click, shows the complete text.

```
<div class="name_loc" id="demo">Name, London</div>
    <div class="readmore">Read more</div>


$('.readmore').each(function() {
$(this).click( function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.content').css('height','100%');
    $(this).hide();
});
```

});

Hope it helps

Comment: Not bad, but if the text does fit, then "read more" doesn't make sense.

Comment: You just need to check out the length of text and show/hide the readme div, it's very simple