# How to clear input with :after element

Tags: javascript, html

Take a look at [this website](http://map.project-osrm.org/). There are 2 search bars and after each search bar there is an `:after` element. When you click that element the text box is cleared. How can I do this with Javascript ? (no jquery)

[image: 1]

Comment: Did you tried something ?

Comment: Like @Oriol and @Nick said. the `event listener` is on the `element`. The pseudo-element is a part of the `current element`. It is not inserted after the element, but after *its content*, within the bounds of the current element, and could be styled with margin... to look like it's outside

Answer (score 3):

[You can't add event listeners to pseudo-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9395858/1529630). But here the element has no contents except the pseudo-element, so you can just add the event listener to the element.

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');
document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function() {
  input.value = '';
});
```

```css
#clear::after {
  content: '\00d7';
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" value="Hello" />
<span id="clear" title="Clear"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

The click event is actually not on the :after pseudo-element, but on the span itself (as you can see [here](http://puu.sh/om3yh/30f80d031d.png)) The pseudo-element just provides the icon, nothing fancy going on here. Then it's just a matter of doing something like this;

```
element.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('startInput').value = '';
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's anything special.
Something like this:

```
var elementList = document.getElementsByClassName('something');
for (var i = 0; i < elementList.length; i++) {
   elementList[i].addEventListener("click", delFn);
}


function delFn(){
console.log("delete it");
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5w4obgzu/1/