# I want to call two different functions on details tag in Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I want to call function A , when someone clicks on the icon of the details and function B when the summary or text section of this detail summary / text is clicked.

```
<details @click="function-A">
            <summary @click="function-B">
                Some Text
            </summary>
        </details>
```

I tried everything, I also used some event modifiers, but it did not work as expected

Comment: "Did not work as expected" doesn't help us to help you :) Can you add details about "what is happening" when you click the elements? Is the wrong function triggered? Nothing happens at all?

Comment: When I click on the summary or the icon of detail it only run the function-A. I also tried using stop or prevent modifiers but it does not work

Comment: Where is the icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arrow icon is a [`::marker` pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker) that is attached to the `summary` element and it's basically impossible to listen to an event on a pseudo element.

A possible work around would be to listen to clicks on the summary element then disabling the point-events for the entire element and enabling it back for the pseudo element, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39161931/10679649) post.

---

If you just want to get the state of the details element (`open`/`closed`), you can use the `toggle` event:

```html
<script setup>
const toggle = (event) => console.log(event.newState, event.oldState)
</script>

<template>
  <details @toggle="toggle">
    <summary>
      Some Text
    </summary>
  </details>
</template>
```

Comment: Where does the OP mention an arrow icon or pseudo element?

Comment: @Kalnode, "when someone clicks on the icon of the details"

Comment: Ok, it's a pretty far stretch to assume that the icon is an arrow and kept as a pseudo-element.

Comment: The question includes a code example using the details element which has this ::marker by default, so it's pretty obvious that the OP is referring to it by "the icon of the details "

Comment: Apologies; I completely overlooked the HTML tags (`details`)! You are correct.

Comment: Thanks both of you for your approach, but this does not work out. As I want to call different functions, but it is not possible to trigger multiple functions on pseudo element (marker). So I found work around  by just building my own detail's tag

Answer (score 0):

### **Use Vue's .stop modifier**

Vue has event modifiers that account for this use case, and the `.stop` modifier should be what you need.

This works for me:
https://codepen.io/MarsAndBack/pen/PoLYPZR

```
<div @click="doSomething" class="container">
  content
  <button @click.stop="doSomething2">
    Some Text
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: If this doesn't work then I'd scrutinize your implementation. Try to remove external factors.

Comment: It won't help since both click will always be registered, the OP wants to listen to "clicks on the icon of the details", using the stop modifier won't help here

Comment: The OP is falsely assuming the listening to clicks on the details element will listen to clicks on the "icon", what actually happens is that both clicks are registered: the click event on the details element & the event on the summary element (which includes the "icon")