# How to target ::backdrop in Javascript to close modal?

Tags: javascript, css, modal-dialog, event-listener, lightbox

I have a modal popup using the dialog element which creates a backdrop pseudo element. i want people to be able to click anywhere that causes the modal to close. However i can't quite target the element to close it out. Below is what i tried. It gives me an error saying it can't read the properties of the event listener. anyone have an idea how to target this pseudo element?

```js
   const openModalButton = document.querySelector(".open-modal");
        const modal = document.querySelector(".video-modal");
        const backdrop = document.querySelector("dialog:-internal-dialog-in-top-layer::backdrop");
        const video = document.querySelector(".video-modal video");

        openModalButton.addEventListener("click", function onOpen() {
          modal.showModal();
          //if we want autoplay, disable comment below
          //video.play();
        });

        modal.addEventListener("close", function onClose() {
          video.pause();
        });
        backdrop.addEventListener("close", function onClose() {
          video.pause();
        });
```

```css
#retirement-services dialog.video-modal {
  border: none;
  padding: 40px;
  border-radius: 21px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
#retirement-services .video-modal-close {
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 16px;
  top: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #e5e1de;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
#retirement-services .open-modal {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
    <div class="col open-modal">
              <div class="play-button open-modal" style="position: absolute">
              click me
              </div>
             
              <dialog class="video-modal">
                <form method="dialog">
                  <button class="video-modal-close">X</button>
                </form>
                <video controls width="220">
                  <source
                    src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"
                    type="video/mp4"
                  />
                </video>
              </dialog>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You [cannot assign events to pseudo-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395858/event-listener-on-a-css-pseudo-element-such-as-after-and-before). However, an click event will be triggered even when the dialog's backdrop background is clicked, so you can make use of the click event on the modal instead.

In the handler, use `e.target === e.currentTarget` to check that the event is not bubbled up by the child elements of the modal.

```js
const openModalButton = document.querySelector(".open-modal");
const modal = document.querySelector(".video-modal");
const video = document.querySelector(".video-modal video");

openModalButton.addEventListener("click", function onOpen() {
  modal.showModal();
});

modal.addEventListener("close", function onClose() {
  video.pause();
});

document.querySelector(".video-modal").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target === e.currentTarget) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    modal.close();
  }
})
```

```css
#retirement-services dialog.video-modal {
  border: none;
  padding: 40px;
  border-radius: 21px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#retirement-services .video-modal-close {
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 16px;
  top: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #e5e1de;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#retirement-services .open-modal {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="col open-modal">
  <div class="play-button open-modal" style="position: absolute">
    click me
  </div>

  <dialog class="video-modal">
    <form method="dialog">
      <button class="video-modal-close">X</button>
    </form>
    <video controls width="220">
        <source
          src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"
          type="video/mp4"
        />
      </video>
  </dialog>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it is not possible to bind an eventlistener to a pseudo element. instead you can add a eventlistener to document and check if the click happens outside of your dialog by using the event composedpath method.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composedPath